# Login through facebook sdk in android

Tags: android, facebook

I am using facebook sdk to log in through my app. The codes I am following is given at 
`<https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/>`

But when I am clicking on the button **" Log in with facebook "** the button is not changing. The button should change to **" Log out "**. I am getting following in log cat

```
02-02 12:43:49.349: D/dalvikvm(26836): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3788K, 32% free  10586K/15363K, paused 17ms+9ms, total 142ms   
02-02 12:43:49.349: W/CursorWrapperInner(26836): Cursor finalized without prior close()
02-02 12:43:49.359: W/CursorWrapperInner(26836): Cursor finalized without prior close()
02-02 12:43:49.359: W/CursorWrapperInner(26836): Cursor finalized without prior close()
02-02 12:43:49.369: W/CursorWrapperInner(26836): Cursor finalized without prior close()
02-02 12:43:49.369: W/CursorWrapperInner(26836): Cursor finalized without prior close()
02-02 12:43:49.399: W/CursorWrapperInner(26836): Cursor finalized without prior close()
02-02 12:43:49.399: W/CursorWrapperInner(26836): Cursor finalized without prior close()
02-02 12:43:49.399: W/CursorWrapperInner(26836): Cursor finalized without prior close()
02-02 12:43:49.409: W/CursorWrapperInner(26836): Cursor finalized without prior close()
02-02 12:43:49.419: D/AbsListView(26836): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
02-02 12:43:49.439: I/MotionRecognitionManager(26836):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0,  
02-02 12:43:49.439: W/CursorWrapperInner(26836): Cursor finalized without prior close()
02-02 12:43:49.459: W/CursorWrapperInner(26836): Cursor finalized without prior close()
02-02 12:43:49.489: E/SpannableStringBuilder(26836): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
02-02 12:43:49.489: E/SpannableStringBuilder(26836): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
02-02 12:43:55.569: I/MainFragment(26836): Logged out...
02-02 12:43:55.619: I/MainFragment(26836): Logged out...
```

**Log cat is not showing "Log in" executed.**

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use  `easyfacebookandroidsdk.jar` library refer this [step by step procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728207/how-to-integrate-facebook-share-diolouge-to-attach-url-and-image/20730002#20730002).

It is easy than facebook sdk as the name suggests.
 Try this by making a new project.